# NSLocalizedString não reconhece as strings do Localizable.strings

Tags: string, swift, localização

Seguinte estou tentando usar o sistema de localização de string do swift, mas aparentemente ele não reconhece as strings, por exemplo ao invés de aparecer a string Inicio aparece txtinicio, estou tentando acessar as strings assim :

```
NSLocalizedString("txtinicio", comment: "")
```

Minhas configurações estão assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu arquivo de strings esta com as strings assim :

```
"txtinicio" = "Início";
```

Configuração do arquivo de strings esta assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema definitivamente, o que estava acontecendo e que no framework que eu estava usando ele usava localizable, e utilizava o arquivo default Localizable.strings, no meu projeto o arquivo de strings tambem tinha esse nome, a solução foi mudar o nome do arquivo de strings no meu projeto, funcionou